# Фильтр в Django по дате

Tags: python, django, filter

Как сделать, чтобы выводились по дате сначала новые записи, потом более старые.
Сейчас выводится наоборот сначала старые

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from post.models import Post
from django.utils import timezone

def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'frontend/home.html', {'posts': posts})
```

**Модель:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "post"

    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', default='user')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text_preview = models.TextField(max_length=100, default='')
    image_preview = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'img/', default='')
    text = models.TextField(default='')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, чтобы вывести записи по убыванию, надо в order_by перед названием поля поставить "-".

```
def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
    return render(request, 'frontend/home.html', {'posts': posts})
```